# PackageStates.php exception in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I am trying to clear TYPO3 caches at the command line by running `/var/www/vhosts/****/typo3/sysext/core/bin/typo3 cache:flush --group all` but am getting the below error. What could be causing this? The file it seems unable to find is seems to be located at `releases/RELEASE/src/typo3conf/PackageStates.php`, and does not appear corrupt.

```
Uncaught TYPO3 Exception #1381507733: The PackageStates.php file is either corrupt or unavailable.
thrown in file /var/www/vhosts/hrb.ie/typo3/typo3_src-8.7.45/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Package/PackageManager.php
in line 247
```

Comment: Please add more details about your custom setup. Neither `typo3_config` nor context-aware `PackageStates.php` files exist in TYPO3: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-inside/8.7/en-us/CoreArchitecture/Extensions/Index.html

Comment: Apologies, trying to get my head around a foreign system. Looks like that file is copied into `releases/RELEASE/src/typo3conf/PackageStates.php` on deploy

Comment: OK, can you clearly state your TYPO3 version? Your output indicates TYPO3v8 but [`cache:flush --groups` was introduced with TYPO3v11](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/11.4/Feature-90197-IntroduceCacheFlushConsoleCommand.html).

Comment: Yes, this is 8..7.45 so I guess that explains it! I would have expected a complaint that the command doesn't exist though, no?

Comment: Correct, but it looks like when this command is executed your custom logic to prepare the final `PackageStates.php` was not executed, so it may simply be missing. This causes TYPO3 itself to stop early, before even trying to execute the command.

Comment: The file is definitely in the location I mentioned, the application hasn't been redeployed in some time. But thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I would assume a access-right conflict.

The file is created be TYPO (Web-user) and if you call the cmd-line command to clear the cache you are running in the context of your user.

If you missed to set the file-mask in the TYPO3 configuration (LocalConfiguration.php) the file may be created with 644.

Maybe even your user is not in the same group than the web user.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be, the user I'm logged in as is the same as the owner of the file.